# How do I assign the value of grep into a variable and concatenate with a string?

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I have a couple of servers on my development machine. I have a script each to run them and I am working on a few git branches at a time. So whenever I am running the script that runs the server, I want it to print which server from which branch of git I am trying to run in a different color.

Here is what I have but it is not working properly.

```
git_branch= git branch|grep '*'|cut -c3-
echo -e "\e[1;33;40m Running API server on git branch  $git_branch \e[0m"
...
REST_OF_THE_CODE_THAT_RUNS_THE_DEV_SERVER
...
```

It prints the git branch first and the value does not seem to be assigned to the variable at all. I am not able to figure out where I am going wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To assign the result of a command line to a variable, use backquotes or `$(..)` notation.  For example, assuming your command line works, you could use:

```
git_branch=$(git branch|grep '*'|cut -c3-)
```

This notation is preferable to backquotes because it's more easily readable, and allows nesting without the need to escape things:

```
echo $(echo foo$(echo bar))
```

Note that in your original code, your `grep` should be more specific.  Remember that an asterisk really means "zero or more of the previous atom", to grep.  So this would be better:

```
git_branch=$(git branch|grep '^[*]'|cut -c3-)
```